# How to compile gsoap with eclipse?

Tags: c++, eclipse, gsoap

I'm trying compile gsoap on eclipse but i get this error:

```
make: *** [ACWS] Error 1
undefined reference to `namespaces'
undefined reference to `soap_default_ns1__armedNotification(soap*,ns1__armedNotification*)' 
.....
....
```

I think it's a problem of linked but i not solve it.

How can I fix it?

Excuse me for my English

Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you've missed is the #include directive for the .nsmap file generated by gsoap. Check the gsoap manual for references to nsmap (section 1.2 is a good place to start).